# image not getting displayed in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Home.php(file in controller)

```
<?php   
    class Home extends CI_Controller {  
        public function index() {           
            $this->load->helper('url');         
            //display home page
            $this->load->view('home.html'); 
        } 
    }   
?>
```

home.html(file in view page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>PortFolio Website</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
        .navbar {
          margin-bottom: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
        }

        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        /* First Container */
        .bg {
            /* The image used */
            background-image: url("1.jpg");

            /* Full height */
            height: 60%; 

            /* Center and scale the image nicely */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        @media (max-width: 800px) {
           .bg {
               height:80%; 
           }
        }

         /* Second container */
        .bg1 {
            background-color: #f77a55;
            height:45%; 
        }

        @media (max-width: 800px) {
           .bg1 {
               height:70%; 
           }
        }
         /* Third container */
        .bg2 {
            height:40%; 
        }

        @media (max-width: 800px) {
           .bg2 {
               height:100%; 
           }
        }

        /* Fourth container */
        .bg3 {
            background-color: #404040;
            height:60%; 
        }

        @media (max-width: 800px) {
            .bg3 {
                height:190%; 
            }
        }

        /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
        footer {
          background-color: #404040;
          padding: 25px;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
    <body>

        <!--Navigation Bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Full-stack Developer</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!--li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li-->
                    <li><a href="#AboutMe">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/Design/Register.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/Design/login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!--First Container-->
        <div class="bg">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <h1 style="color:White"><strong>Ready For? Engaging Website||</strong></h1> 
                <h2 style="color:White">Inventive Web design, Development & Android Application!</h2>
            </div>  
        </div>  

        <!--Second Container-->
        <div id="AboutMe" class="bg1">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <br><br><br>
                <h1 style="color:White"><strong>About Me</strong></h1> 
                <br>
                <p style="color:White; font-size: 15px"><b>I'm a Full stack developer providing complete Web solutions to the clients. I have a deep technical knowledge combined with the broad digital media work, website designing and development experience means I can provide you with honest suggestions on what can be delivered with your available resource. My aim is to out perform expectations at every possible chance.</b></p> 
            </div>  
        </div>

        <!--Third Container-->
        <div id="Services" class="bg2">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <br><br><br>
                <h1 style="color:#f77a55"><strong>Services</strong></h1> 
            </div><br><br><br>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-desktop text-primary mb-3 sr-icons"></i>
                          <h4 class="mb-3">Responsive Web App Development</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-tablet text-primary mb-3 sr-icons"></i>
                          <h4 class="mb-3">Mobile App Development</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-television text-primary mb-3 sr-icons"></i>
                          <h4 class="mb-3">UI/UX Development</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                          <i class="fa fa-4x fa-cloud text-primary mb-3 sr-icons"></i>
                          <h4 class="mb-3">Hosting & Support service</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br><br><br>

        <!--Fourth Container-->
        <div id="Portfolio" class="bg3">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <br><br>
                <h1 style="color:#f77a55"><strong>Portfolio</strong></h1> 
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url('image/5.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="image" > 
                        <h4 class="mb-3" style="color:orange">Blue Star Power</h4>
                        <p style="color:white">Blue Star Power Solutions Private Limited are specialists in Diesel Generator Sales and Service, Annual Maintenance.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <img src="6.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="image" > 
                        <h4 class="mb-3" style="color:orange">Cavotec Inspired Engineering</h4>
                        <p style="color:white">Global-Airport Solutions is the global industry’s number one meeting place for Airport Operators/Owners,Managers.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <img src="10.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="image" >
                        <h4 class="mb-3" style="color:orange">Gemalto Security Free</h4>
                        <p style="color:white">You will find our identity authentication and data protection technologies at the heart of modern life, Annual Maintenance.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <img src="11.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="image" >
                        <h4 class="mb-3" style="color:orange">Singularity University</h4>
                        <p style="color:white">Our programs and events equip you with the mindset, tools, and resources to successfully journey to the future. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br><br><br>

        <!--fiveth container-->

        <div id="Contact" class="container">
            <h2 class="container text-center" style="color:orange"><b>Let's Get In Touch!</b></h2>
            <p class="container text-center" style="color:orange"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Submit the form and we will get back to you as soon as possible!</span></p><br><br>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="color:red">Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="color:red">Email:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="color:red">Contact Number:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_number" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" name="contact_number">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="color:red">Subject:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Enter Reason For Contacting..." name="subject"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">        
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div><br>

        <!--Footer-->
        <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
            <h4 style="color:white">2018 @ Full-Stack Developer</h4>  
            <p style="color:white">All Rights Reserved</p>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have done a simple design with bootstrap, which is working fine in local host but when i try to enter it in my codeignitor folder its not working, i mean to say the images 
which are their in the page are not getting displayed when i tried it to open via codeignitor, i have saved all my images in view folder itself, i know this is really 
a stupid question.

i tried with this but its not working

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('image/5.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="image" >
```

Comment: view must have .php extension $this->load->view('home.html');

Comment: i have done what actually ur telling but actually what im facing probiem is my banner image and rest other images are not getting dispalyed in the design

Comment: First your file name should have with php extension and Second make sure you added url helper in autoload.php or in your controller.

Comment: my home.html should be home.php?

Comment: yes, also check the base path is correct or not and also include url helper

Comment: sir ifwe use any other extension like html and all then in our controller we have to give like home.html isn't it?

Comment: We can't write php code in html file.

Comment: You can use .html for the view file names but as @rawathemant just pointed out, if you do you cannot use PHP scripting in the file. You will want to use PHP in view files from time to time.

Comment: if 'image/5.jpg' really the file name of the image?

Comment: Can you please write absolute url of your image folde?

Comment: have u set your base_url in your config.php

Answer (score 0):

**If your images are in public/images directory and your
Base URL is**

(**you can check/set your base URL in /application/config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'enter your base path here';
```

)

if your basepath is

> www.yoururl.com/

then use path

```
 <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/image/5.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can't use .html file, because in html file you can't write php code.
2. helper 'url' must be loaded in autoload.php, either in view page you have to load again helper url.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store images in view folder.

You should check some following step-

1) first fix your project `base_url` which is set in `application/config/config.php`

2) create a folder(e.g: image) on application location for save all images. then you can 
   save any img(e.g:5.jpg) in this folder which you are want.

3) on final step where you want to display image use code like this-

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/image/5.jpg">
```